# Where can I find the history of military uniforms?

Tags: military, uniform

Is there any web resource that talk about the history and evolution of military uniforms?

For example, development, history and evolution of uniforms of various Muslim, European, Asian, Indian empires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've visted this site many a times, very interesting. Should provide what your looking for

http://www.militaryheritage.com/

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't any single web site that will give you examples of military uniforms throughout the world and throughout time. You would have better luck searching by specific countries. To help with this, I have found a couple of links that focus on [US](http://www.tekawiz.com/thumbcontents.html) and [British](http://www.victorianstrollers.co.uk/stevesuniforms/index.html) uniforms. Each has pictures with many different uniform styles throughout time as well as information about some of the uniforms.

Answer (score 0):

Through my years of research on the subject i haven't found a specific website covering the evolution uniforms of a large of armies . Instead you will have to search invidually for websites covering the evolution of a specific army but there is a few covering the uniforms of different armies during period. You can go on Wikipedia pages, news articles to do with uniforms or forums too because there are a lot of experts on them.
Here are some good websites on uniformology.

- [napolun](http://www.napolun.com/mirror/napoleonistyka.atspace.com/index.html)
- [KaisersBunker](http://www.kaisersbunker.com/)
- [GermanColonialUniforms](http://www.germancolonialuniforms.co.uk/)
- [Tacitus](https://www.tacitus.nu/gnw/index.htm)
- [hhogman.se](http://www.hhogman.se/uniforms-navy-sweden-start.htm)
- [BritishEmpire](https://www.britishempire.co.uk/index.htm)

The best way to find these sites is to type in the language of the country you're looking for and simply translate the website which I found to be the most effective method at finding the information you want.
Feel free to make a comment if you need help on specific uniforms of a certain country.